# How can I save my file after writing to it in Python?

Tags: python

I am learning python, and followed a guide for a quick and simple reddit bot. I wanted to try my skills and attempted to make a cache.txt file to write the comments that I have replyed to. Currently, the file opens, and the code runs, and writes the comment ID to the file correctly, but when I close the program, sometimes the cache.txt file clears, and the program needs to rerun and it replys to the same comments again. Is there a certain function I have to call in order for the cache file to save so when I stop the program the text will remain?

Comment: Please show us your code.

Comment: See [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to `.close()` the file.